# Run oracle script using java code

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I wrote a program to run oracle (oracle11g) script using java code but when i m run program it gives error:

```
ORA-00900:"invalid SQL statement".
```

Queries are:

```
execute dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'STORAGE',false);
execute dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'TABLESPACE',false);
execute dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', false);
execute dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'REF_CONSTRAINTS', false);
execute dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'CONSTRAINTS', false);
```

Code:

```
String Query = "execute dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'STORAGE',false);"
Statement st = con.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate(Query);
```

Comment: Format your code please

Comment: To ask the obvious: Can you execute that query from your Oracle console without error?  My guess is that you can't.

Comment: No I can run script using oracle console and also getting same error when i execute script using oracle11g developer tool but when i run script then it run without any error.

Comment: **EXECUTE** is **SQL*Plus command**, I am not sure about Java. Also, you need to execute them in a **PL/SQL** block.

Comment: I can easily execute  this command in sql*plus but i want to execute it with java.

Comment: For what it's worth: Oracle JDBS does not like trailing ; in SQL - this causes exactly the error you see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need call the procedure via anonymous block in java
use `begin ... end` instead of `execute`

```
String Query = "begin dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'STORAGE',false); end;"
Statement st = con.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate(Query);
```

Comment: Did it work for you?  I am seeing `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 12:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DBMS_METADATA" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "DBMS_METADATA" to continue.`

Comment: `Connected to Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 
 
SQL> begin dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'STORAGE',false); end;
  2  /
 
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
 
SQL> show errors;
No errors
 
SQL> `